# Create a swipe feature within an UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview

In my current test app I have a `UITabBarController`, linked to a `UINavigationController` that leads to a `UIViewController` with 6 buttons in it and a second `UIViewController` with a `UIImageView`. I've created a segue for each button, wich works.

I want to be able to create a swipe pictures feature inside that `UIImageView`. The source pictures are inside the app's folder.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your question.

If you need to create a sort of slider of images, you could create a `UIViewController` with a `UIScrollView`as the main view (or as a subview of `UIViewController`'s `view`).

Once set up, you could create a `for-loop` where you create `UIImageView` elements to wrap the image you are loading from your app folder and add each `UIImageView` to the scroll view.

To make possible to snap photos within the `UIScrollView` set its property `pagingEnabled` to `YES`.

For further info you could take a look at [Scrolling](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008023-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) sample provided by Apple.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks ! By using the Scrolling example, now it ...works ! But...altough the pagingEnabled=YES it does not snaps. Some piece of code is over writting this feature => the pictures bounce around because they can be scrolled horizontally and vertically at the same time.
Thanks for help anyway!

Comment: @LAOMUSICARTS You're welcome. If you want, you can mark my answer as correct or upvote if you found it useful. Furthermore, I guess the snap could not work since your image size could be greater then the scroll view frame. Let me know. Cheers.